# How to make a div inside a td to stretch?

Tags: html, css

I have a table like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td><div class="stretch"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the `.stretch` to fit the height of the `td`. Currently the `div` has a height of 0. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, what's the table like? Can you post the html/css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the td must have a set size
then you set the div's height:100%;
or inherit pretty the same thing
and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 1):

```
.stretch {
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<table style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: thin solid #FF0000; height:200px">            
            <div style="border: thin solid #0000FF;  width:100%; height:100%;">

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```